# How to use mounted non-system drive as storage for database Docker container?

Tags: docker, bind, volume, docker-desktop

I'm writing as a beginner docker user.

### My Objective:

- To run a `couchdb` container on my local machine simply using the image found at https://github.com/apache/couchdb-docker/blob/main/README.md
- Use a pre-mounted, non-boot SATA HDD as the device for database storage. To my understanding so far, a bind mount is an easy solution as I should be able to specify the (from the host's perspective) mount source path. However, I'm open to using Volumes as well.

### Docker and System Info

- Linux fedora 6.6.6-200.fc39.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC
- Docker Desktop v4.26.1 using defaults

### Run Script

Before beginning, the device is confirmed to be mounted in the host filesystem at the designated path.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
docker run --name couchdb \
    -p 5984:5984 \
    -v /run/media/username/devicelabel/Docker/couchdb/mount/data:/opt/couchdb/data \
    -e COUCHDB_USER=adminname \
    -e COUCHDB_PASSWORD=adminpassword \
    -d couchdb && \

# Wait for container
sleep 5 && \

# Create required databases
curl -X PUT http://adminname:adminpassword@127.0.0.1:5984/_users && \
curl -X PUT http://adminname:adminpassword@127.0.0.1:5984/_replicator && \
curl -X PUT http://adminname:adminpassword@127.0.0.1:5984/_global_changes
```

### Result

Running this script results in what appears to be a successful binding where data is persisted whenever I delete the container and rebuild.

The problem: the data isn't stored in the specified mount point, on the host, at /run/media/username/devicelabel/Docker/couchdb/mount/data; I do not know where the data is being persisted between container builds, however restarting Docker Desktop purges the data.

### Inspect

Here are some snippets from `docker inspect`:

Config.Volumes (I'm assuming the default Volume in the dockerfile)

```
            "Volumes": {
                "/opt/couchdb/data": {}
            },
```

Mounts

```
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/run/media/username/devicelabel/Docker/couchdb/mount/data",
                "Destination": "/opt/couchdb/data",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
```

### Additional

Replacing the `-v` option with something like

```
...
--mount type=bind,source=/run/media/username/devicelabel/Docker/couchdb/mount/data,target=/opt/couchdb/data \
...
```

Results in an error, and failure to run:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /run/media/username/devicelabel/Docker/couchdb/mount/data.
```

Comment: Is /run/media/username/devicelabel/Docker/couchdb/mount/data the path where you mounted the SSD to?

Comment: /run/media/user/devicelabel is the mountpoint, and the rest are nested directories, with /data being the directory I'd like bound to the container's /opt/couchdb/data

Comment: When running `docker run --rm --name couchdb -p 5984:5984 -v /mount_test/whatever:/opt/couchdb/data -e COUCHDB_USER=adminname -e COUCHDB_PASSWORD=adminpassword -d couchdb` (pretty much what you tried), where `/mount_test` is a mounted drive, this works just fine, with CouchDB putting its files into `/mount_test/whatever` on my machine.

Comment: Using that will start the container on my end, but I'm unable to see the data in the path on the host side. But it shows data inside the container at /opt/couchdb/data that is supposedly bound.

Comment: Hmm, weird. Which OS are you on?

Comment: Yep - I'm wondering I might be doing something wrong fundamentally. My OS is Fedora Workstation 39, kernel 6.6.6-200.fc39.x86_64

Comment: Is the SSD filesystem just regular ext4?

Comment: The filesystem is btrfs

Comment: hmm, it was btrfs for me, too... Could you share the mount options? You might find them in /etc/fstab.

Comment: rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,seclabel,space_cache=v2,subvolid=5,subvol=/,uhelper=udisks2 (is that the right info?)

Comment: Okay, tbh I don't have too much of a clue. But could you check the output of `mount`? Are you sure that only the btrfs SSD is mounted to that path?

Comment: Another avenue: Does the bind mount work when you use a different path, e.g. /home/username/temp_mount or /temp_mount ?

Comment: It works whenever mounting a directory on my boot/system ssd, just not on that device, no matter the path. 

Mount and systemctl show the expected mount point. However the device isn't listed in fstab (im not sure if thats a concern)

Comment: I did just notice that, in the path that works, the user and group are set to "530271" after mounting successfully with only read permission for others (such as my login user). The user and group in the non-working path is recursively my login user and group. Not sure if that's a clue.